# Rails Controller Genereate Contrroller Error

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, controller, generate

When I run `rails g controller rooms show`

I get `error    js [not found]` , but js seems to be reasonably symlinked to node, because when I `"which js"`, I get `/usr/bin/js`, and  when I do `"js --help"`, I get node.js info: `"Usage: node [options] [ -e script | script.js | - ] [arguments]"`

Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you able to run your application with `rails -s`? Is this only occurring when trying to create a new controller?

Comment: Scilence: I don't know. I did what one sometimes has to do: I ripped out huge parts of code, effectively stepping back 5 steps, and moved forward again.  Don't know what caused the problem and can't reproduce it. I'd delete the question if I knew how to do so.  Thanks though!